# What HTTP status code should I return for POST when no resource is created?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

I am posting an image to my server (usign Java and Spring).

A couple of things can happen:

- If everything goes well, then I return `200` and the image id.
- The image can't be saved to the file system (`SaveFileException`).
- The database can't update the new image record with the new URL (`DatabaseException`).
- Or throw an `IOException`.

In short, I can not save/create the image.

What HTTP code should I return?

Should I return more than one code and more than one message according to the `Exception`?

Comment: The sorts of problems you describe here are internal errors (5xx), since they are nothing to do with the user asking you to do the wrong thing.

Comment: [This tweet](https://twitter.com/stevelosh/status/372740571749572610) is a surprisingly accurate summary of the HTTP status code ranges.

Comment: I think it is important to specify the difference between errors caused by the client (wrong file, too large, wrong message etc) and errors caused by the service/backend. Right now your question is fairly generic, and so will the answer as well.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

First of all, let me highlight that status codes are meant to indicate the result of the sever's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's request.

> *If everything goes well, then I return `200` and the image id.*

Seems to be fine, but I would advise you to return `201` along with a [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header instead. Quoting the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) regarding the `POST` method:

> If one or more resources has been created on the origin server as a result of successfully processing a `POST` request, the origin server SHOULD send a `201` (Created) response containing a `Location` header field that provides an identifier for the primary resource created and a representation that describes the status of the request while referring to the new resource(s).

Along with `201`, the [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header is meant to indicate where the newly created resource is located. If no `Location` header is provided, then the client should assume that the resource is identified by the effective request URI:

> [**6.3.2.  201 Created**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2)
>
> The `201` (Created) status code indicates that the request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created.  The primary resource created by the request is identified by either a `Location` header field in the response or, if no `Location` field is received, by the effective request URI. [...]

---

### Client error

Can the client perform a new request and fix the issue? If so, pick a status code in the `4xx` range:

> [**6.5.  Client Error 4xx**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)
>
> The `4xx` (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a `HEAD` request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.  These status codes are applicable to any request method.

[Michael Kropat](https://www.codetinkerer.com/about) put together a very useful [set of flowcharts](https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html) that may give you some insighsts. See the following chart to determine the most suitable `4xx` status code:

[image: Choosing a 4xx status code]

Some valid options, depending on what caused the error, are:

> [**6.5.11.  413 Payload Too Large**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.11)
>
> The `413` (Payload Too Large) status code indicates that the server is refusing to process a request because the request payload is larger than the server is willing or able to process. [...]

> [**6.5.13.  415 Unsupported Media Type**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13)
>
> The `415` (Unsupported Media Type) status code indicates that the origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource. The format problem might be due to the request's indicated `Content-Type` or `Content-Encoding`, or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

> [**6.5.1.  400 Bad Request**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)
>
> The `400` (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

---

### Server error

If the error was caused by the server, then a status code in the `5xx` range will be accurate:

> [**6.6.  Server Error 5xx**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6)
>
> The `5xx` (Server Error) class of status code indicates that the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the requested method.  Except when responding to a `HEAD` request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

See the following flowchart:

[image: Choosing a 5xx status code]

I would suggest [`500`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1):

> [**6.6.1.  500 Internal Server Error**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1)
>
> The `500` (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: Although I commend the completeness of the explanation on the 5xx, I think 4xx errors should also be considered depending on what caused the problem.

Comment: Those flowcharts are majestic AF and I am very grateful to you for posting this. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: +1 from me. I had a laugh with the Enhance Your Calm HTTP Status, I had no idea about it. Good flowchart.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the issue that is preventing the image to be posted to server.

If the image or request are not formated correctly, should be 4XX.

eg: a general `400 Bad Request` or specific `415 Unsupported Media Type`, `409 Conflict`, `413 Request Entity Too Large` .

If the problem is a server side error, the error code should be on the 5XX:

eg. General one: `500 Internal Server Error` or `503 Service Unavailable`, specifics: `507 Insufficient Storage (WebDAV)` `504 Gateway Timeout`

Sometimes being specific about the error can help find a solution to make the POST work. But that depends if you want the error to be avoided and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> The image can't be saved to the file system (Save File Exception).
>
> The database can't update the new image record with the new url
>   (DatabaseException).
>
> Or throw an IOException.
>
> In short, I can not save/create the image.
>
> What http code should I return?

All the specific examples that you cite - Its going to be Internal Server Error ( Http Status - 500 ). There are cases for 409 too.

[Refer This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088414/what-http-error-code-for-failure-to-create-a-new-resource-because-a-parent-entit)

> Should I return more than one code and more than one message according
>   to the Exception.

Customizing messages as per explicit exception is more helpful but in my opinion, its over engineering as client is not the one who is going to fix the issue for these kind of errors. If its client, which is supposed to correct its request then put message according to that ( but usually that is the case for Http Status 400 - Bad Request ).

If client is not the one who is supposed to take an action to fix the issue in any way ( i.e. handle the issue in anyway )  & it simply needs an info about error so put a simple message & Http Status 500.

Answer (score 0):

You may return 500 Internal server exception.